# Declining option based on previous picks

Tags: javascript, menu

I am trying to figure out how to have a menu "shrink" based on previous choices.  Basically I have 5 options and I want users to put them in the order they think is most important, but can not chose an option more than once. I need this to be written in either java or javascript.

i.e.
[option a] (The users chooses one)
Apple
Banana
Dragon Fruit
Pineapple
Papaya

[option b] (The users chose Dragon Fruit in option a)
Apple
Banana
Pineapple
Papaya

[option b] (The users chose pineapple in option b)
Apple
Banana
Papaya

and so on.

Any suggestions on where to start looking?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don;t you do something like jQuery UI Sortable: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide the menu item.
jQuery can help you, it will be something like:

```
$(".item").on("click",function() {
    // react somehow on user's choice
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```